# TypeScript: extend a class that has been loaded via require

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

## Context

We're splitting our current project (TypeScript + RequireJS) into separate modules (core, widget1, ...). We're running version 0.8.1.1 of TypeScript.

Each module is built to a single file, and the core will be loaded initially. The widgets will be lazy loaded, only in case they are needed, but I want to make sure the widgets can reference my core modules (but **not** include the module in their output).

---

**To clarify** when compiling TypeScript to AMD modules, `import` statements will be compiled into the dependency array of the module's `define` function. Example:

TypeScript

```
import coreModule = module("core");
```

JavaScript output (with AMD flag)

```
define(['require', 'exports', 'core'], function(require, exports, __CoreModule__){
    var coreModule = __CoreModule__;
});
```

This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Hence I'm planning on replacing all `import someCoreModule = module("core/...");` statements with `var someCoreModule = require("core/...");` ones.

## Problem

The problem I'm facing is some of these core modules are returning base classes which can be extended by the widgets. Due to the namespacing in TypeScript, this means I need to extend these as follows:

```
import baseClass = module("core/SomeBaseClass");
class Child extends baseClass.Base {
}
```

And ofcourse I still need this same syntax when replacing the `import` statement with a `require` one:

```
var baseClass = require("core/SomeBaseClass");
class Child extends baseClass.Base {
}
```

This obviously results in an error regarding a missing type (Base). I currently plan to circumvent this error by providing a stub implementation of the base class. As follows:

```
declare module baseClass {
    class Base {
    }
}

var baseClass = require("core/SomeBaseClass");
class Child extends baseClass.Base {
}
```

Although this works, I find this rather ugly looking. I need to be able to extend the class as I need calls to `super`. This means I can't use an interface to type the *required* module.

Does anyone know a better solution or am I forced to solve my issue in this way?

As always, any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no way to get the compiler to not generate the additional requirement in the define call.

When using vanilla require statements, you can try to generate a .d.ts from the ts file for you (so that you do not need to add that stub) using the --declaration compiler flag. Hope this helps.

Also sounds like a good feature to have in the compiler (and a simple one to implement I suppose), so you might want to request that here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic (send the link in a comment, I'll definitely vote for it).

Comment: There's a way :) Use `require`instead of `import`. I'm going to look at generating d.ts files for those classes. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as I've found the correct solution on how to separate my widgets from my core (which was the idea behind all this). I'm not sure this should even work in TypeScript (as I described). Thanks for your input anyway :)

Comment: @Anzeo you should post your solution and mark that as answer. Its a perfectly valid thing to do on stackoverflow. You will have to wait 2 days after posting answer before you can do that though.

Comment: I know, but in this case my solution hasn't got the slightest thing to do with this question :/

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong answer. Left for context.**

The problem you are trying to solve : *I want to make sure the widgets can reference my core modules, but won't include these in their output file.*

When you do :

```
import baseClass = module("core/SomeBaseClass");
```

and compile with the `--module 'amd'` compiler flag it creates a `define` and `require` call same as you are trying to achieve. It doesn't pull it in. You can see a sample I created here : https://github.com/basarat/TypeScriptEditor/tree/gh-pages/scripts

Comment: In your example the compiled `CompilationService.js` is exactly doing what I'm trying to avoid :) It compiles the import of `EditorPosition` inside the dependency array of the define call?

Comment: I thought you were trying to avoid the /// <reference style of *bring in the whole file* issue. Any reason why you don't want it in the main define call? Lazy loading?

Comment: Yes indeed, I want lo load the files only when they're needed :)